# Backbone.js - two PUTs

Tags: rest, backbone.js

Good morning!

I use Backbone.js 0.9.2 (and CakePHP). My model has 4 fields: `id`, `name`, `description` and `image_id`. I add models with a `name` and a `description` and get the `id` and `image_id` from the server response and the proper change events fire (`name` and `description` first and `id` and `image_id` later).

Now, when I edit something two PUTs are sent (the resource in this case is `CookingUtensils/144`).
[image]

I see one `change` event for the field I edited and another general one (`change` only and not `change:description`, `change:name` etc). I don't understand why. Both PUT requests have exactly the same body.

- My model: https://gist.github.com/3385347
- My views: https://gist.github.com/3385345
- My collection: https://gist.github.com/3385344

I simply cannot figure out what is going on. Thank you for reading. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is save() firing twice - once for the enter key, and once again onBlur?  Since the values only change once (the first time), you'll only get one change event.  put a console.log on the save method and print out the event.  Or, a breakpoint in chrome debugger/firebug and see what the stack is - what triggered the save.

Comment: Yes, that was it! The model was saved after a key press and after the following blur. Thank you very much! Is there a way to accept a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: I added it as an answer.  Glad to hear it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is save() firing twice - once for the enter key, and once again onBlur?

Since the values only change once (the first time), you'll only get one change event. put a console.log on the save method and print out the event. Or, a breakpoint in chrome debugger/firebug and see what the stack is - what triggered the save. –